# Match bigram frequencies to bigram tokens across multiple columns

Tags: r, match

I have two dataframes, one is a frequency list with bigram frequencies:

```
F_bigrams <- structure(list(word_tag = c("it_PNP 's_VBZ", "do_VDB n't_XX0", 
                                         "that_DT0 's_VBZ", "you_PNP know_VVB", "i_PNP 'm_VBB", "i_PNP do_VDB", 
                                         "in_PRP the_AT0", "i_PNP 've_VHB", "'ve_VHB got_VVN", "i_PNP mean_VVB"
), Freq_bigr = c(31831L, 26273L, 21691L, 14157L, 14010L, 12904L, 
                 10994L, 10543L, 10089L, 9856L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",                                                                                   "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The other contains bigram tokens:

```
df <- data.frame(
  bigr_1_2 = c("i_PNP 'm_VBB", NA, NA, NA),
  bigr_2_3 = c("it_PNP 's_VBZ", "'ve_VHB got_VVN", NA, NA),
  bigr_3_4 = c("you_PNP know_VVB", "it_PNP 's_VBZ", "'ve_VHB got_VVN", NA)
)
```

I want to match the frquencies from the frequency list `F_bigrams` to each bigram token in `df`. This I can do without problems in `df`, which is a tiny snippet of the actual data, with this `base R` method:

```
df[, paste0("f_bigr_", 1:3, "_", 2:4)] <- sapply(df[, 1:3], function(x) F_bigrams$Freq_bigr[match(x, F_bigrams$word_tag)])
```

However, in the actual data, which has far more columns and half a million rows, I consistently get the number `2` where there should be `NA`. Why is that? And, more importantly, is there an **alternative way to match the frequencies to their respective bigram tokens**?

Comment: I don't know where the `2` comes from. Maybe try it this way: `df[paste0("f_", names(df))] <- lapply(df, \(x) F_bigrams$Freq_bigr[match(x, F_bigrams$word_tag)])` what is basically the same like in the question, but maybe comes to the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid, values_to = 'word_tag', values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  left_join(F_bigrams) %>%
  pivot_wider(rowid, values_from = c(word_tag, Freq_bigr))

  rowid word_tag_bigr_1_2 word_tag_bigr_2_3 word_tag_bigr_3_4 Freq_bigr_bigr_1_2 Freq_bigr_bigr_2_3 Freq_bigr_bigr_3_4
  <int> <chr>             <chr>             <chr>                          <int>              <int>              <int>
1     1 i_PNP 'm_VBB      it_PNP 's_VBZ     you_PNP know_VVB               14010              31831              14157
2     2 NA                've_VHB got_VVN   it_PNP 's_VBZ                     NA              10089              31831
3     3 NA                NA                've_VHB got_VVN                   NA                 NA              10089
```

Comment: Cool. I've added this to shorten the col names: `rename_with(~ sub("^Freq_bigr", "f", .), matches("^Freq_bigr"))`